# Passing MySQL query results to Javascript/Jquery in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, mysql, django

I am trying to send mysql query results in the context of my Django template to a Javascript variable. I am using pivot.js https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable which requires jquery and the jquery UI.

In the Django view:

```
cursor.execute(query)
data = dictfetchall(cursor)
json_data = json.dumps(data, cls=DateTimeEncoder)
context['pivot_data'] = json_data
```

This works and I am able to see the data in the javascript console but for some reason it is not formatted properly.

From my Django template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static "js/pivot.js" %}"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var pivotData = '{{ pivot_data }}';
    $("#output").pivotUI(
        pivotData,
        {
            rows: ["XXX"],
            cols: ["YYY"]
        }
        );
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is going to be a string (it's a JSON object that you quoted):

```
var pivotData = '{{ pivot_data }}';
```

You can do:

```
var pivotData = {{ pivot_data }};
```

But this is bad practice, as it's akin to eval-ing the JSON data (and will fail certain on special characters, as [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)).

A better approach would be:

```
var pivotData = JSON.parse('{{ pivot_data }}');
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. I ended up using:var pivotData = JSON.parse('{{ pivot_data|escapejs }}');

Comment: Thank you for leaving the comment @user3453012. I HAD to have the `|escapejs` for it to work. super helpful question and answer :)